# Alamofire upload with URLEncodedInURL parameters?

Tags: parameters, upload, alamofire

I'm new to iOS/Swift and I just started playing with Alamofire 3.4.0.  I've used it successfully for a number of GET/POST requests.  Now I'm trying to use it to upload a file as MultipartFormData.  The problem I'm running into is that I need to include a couple of URLEncodedInURL parameters.  For example, my URL to upload looks like:

```
PUT http://myserver.com:9972/api/files/9ac474e0&uploadToken=23rjv019r325r87a
```

In the GET/POST requests that I've written so far, I've been using the request() overload that include `parameters` as well as `encoding` arguments but I don't see a similar overload for uploads?  Most of the upload examples I've seen that include parameters seem to write them into the multipart form data using `.appendBodypart()` but I haven't seen anything that deals with URL-encoded parameters in the URL itself.

As I said before, Alamofire is still pretty new to me so I'm guessing that I'm just missing something obvious.  If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd certainly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is how I "should" be doing it, but I was able to get this working simply by including my URL parameters as a part of the `URLString` argument to `Alamofire.upload()`.  Since Alamofire's `.request()`has arguments for parameters and encoding, I was thinking that there would be an overload of `.upload()` that had the same.  If there is a better way of including URL parameters when uploading a file as multipart form data using Alamofire, I'd still appreciate it if someone could point it out.  Thanks!